# How to make ngInfiniteScroll run in Bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, nginfinitescroll

I'm in need of using ngInfiniteScroll for a gallery in a modal, but it seems not to work. It does not accept to scroll in this Bootstrap UI modal. Do you know any way to do this, pls let me know! Thanks.
[image]

https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 6):

Use following attributes in your image container which is inside angular ui modal.

```
infinite-scroll-container="'.modal'"
```

This should work.

Its not documented, but to get more information visit this thread
https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/pull/7

Comment: For those who still can't fix it - this comment helped me
https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/pull/7#issuecomment-42402768

Also I've updated ngInfiniteSroll to 1.3.0 (note that 1.3.0 is not available from their site, but you can download it from https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/releases/tag/1.3.0 )